# Reading pdf with TM package

Tags: r, tm

I am trying to read pdf files with the TM package. I have gone through succesfully in most of the attempts, but one. I have several folders with hundreds of documents each. I have read all of them but one. The problem is that the pdfs in that specific folder have a sequence of images on the bottom of the first page that prevents me from reading them. I get the following error:

```
Error in strptime(d, fmt) : input string is too long
```

If I remove the first page, I manage to read them. I could do it without much loss of relevant information, but it is too much work.

I try with xpdf and ghoststring, but both give me the same error.

My code is as following:

```
library(rvest)
library(tm)
url<-paste0("http://www.tjrj.jus.br/search?q=acidente+de+transito+crianca+atropelamento&btnG=Pesquisar&processType=cnj&site=juris&client=juris&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=juris&entqrm=0&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1&filter=0&getfields=*&partialfields=(ctd:1)&exclude_apps=1&ulang=en&lr=lang_pt&sort=date:D:S:d1&as_q=+&access=p&entqr=3&start=",seq(0,462,10))

css<-sprintf(".margin-top-10:nth-child(%.d) .outros .featured",1:10)

for (j in 1:1){ # There 47 pages, but I only put one here 
for (i in 1:10){ # there are 10 files per page.
a<-html_node(css=css[i]) %>% 
html_attr("href")
download.file(a,paste0("doc",j,i,".pdf"))
}
}

files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
Rpdf <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))
docs <- Corpus(URISource(files,encoding="UTF-8"),readerControl = list(reader = Rpdf,language="portuguese"))
```

Does someone have a suggestion? I use a Mac.

Comment: Could you provide the `download.file` statement to get the PDF to make this reproducible?

Comment: Sure. I edited to add the process of downloding the files.

Comment: Thanks much. OK How about `arquivos`, where does that object come from?

Comment: Try the `pdftools` library and see if `pdf_text(filename)` solves your problem. I was able to read the complete text for the 10th pdf.

Comment: Hack-R, translated "arquivos" to English "files" and skipped that word.

Comment: R. Schifini. It worked with pdftools. Thank you. I will stick with that, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work with tm package.  I am almost giving up on tm package.

Comment: I am also stuck at reading pdf files through the `tm` R package. Does anyone know how to pass the `upw=` parameter to the `readPDF` function generator? My pdf files are password protected and they are read by `pdftools::pdf_text` function successfully but when I generate the function by `readPDF(control = list(upw="12345678")) -> read_statement` it gives an error :
`Error in poppler_pdf_text(loadfile(pdf), opw, upw) : 
  PDF file is locked. Invalid password?` Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer:

But I recently discovered that with the current verions of tm (0.7-4) readPDF uses pdftools as default to read pdfs.

```
library(tm)

directory <- getwd() # change this to directory where pdf-files are located

# read the pdfs with readPDF, default engine used is pdftools see ?readPDF for more info
my_corpus <- VCorpus(DirSource(directory, pattern = ".pdf"), 
                               readerControl = list(reader = readPDF))
```